# Is there any non-prototype laptop with e-ink display?

Tags: laptop

I have been blown away by the Kindle display. I thought for myself, "I want to have this display on a notebook!", since I read a lot on my PC - I thought it would be great with bash-only distro of linux (since there are text browsers like Links) - and I spend a lot of hours coding, which means just staring into text, and my eyes often hurt. I understand it would be black and white only.

But all I found are prototypes that never materialized.

So, my question is, are there some e-ink notebooks that I can actually buy?

Comment: I've not seen one yet, and after using a Sony Reader with high-speed e-ink (which is a HUGE improvement over earlier ones like the Kindle, etc.) I can see why.  It's just laggy enough to drive one batty trying to use it as anything other than a book.

Comment: Well, I am prepared that I won't be able to play flash games on my dream device, but I though it might be OK for text-oriented stuff, like coding or running text-only applications. Oh well.

Comment: You can now ask at [hardware recommendations SE](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com). (well, check [here](http://www.solcomputer.com/sunlight-readable-netbook.html)) I've added [similar question](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2415/1466) there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of e-ink is to display stuff that doesn't change a lot - it takes energy to prepare the display (move ink in capsules) but than you don't need energy to keep the display on. This is perfect for books, when you need a minute or two to read a page.

It is not designed for constantly refreshing displays.

Answer (score 0):

There is a list (some are prototypes, some are not) [here](http://www.eink.com/customer_showcase_eReaders.html)

Comment: The article you linked to specifically mentions that it's not an E-Ink display, it's some form of TFT LCD.

Comment: @Mark Henderson. So it did. Revised.